# SetParent() on a VB6 application from a C# app

Tags: c#, winapi, vb6

I am trying to use the win32 API to set the parent of an application to a panel in my C# application.

When I inspect it using Spy++ the application loads in 2 main forms `ThunderRT6Main` and `ThunderRT6MDIForm` both with the same title.

I have found the handle of both of these and tried to call `SetParent` on them both but the window does nothing and does not move anywhere...

Is there something funky I need to do when invoking `SetParent()` on a VB6 app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ThunderRT6Main` is the hidden owner of every top level form in VB6. It sets the application icon, the one you see in the Applications tab of Task Manager. You can read this interesting article

[A window can have a parent or an owner but not both](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2010/03/15/9978691.aspx)

Basicly you might need `WS_CHILD` set before calling `SetParent`.